# In linux In which file ip address of my system is present

Tags: c, linux, networking

From which file ifconfig command takes input for displaying ip address, inet addr and h/w addr ?. I want this information for my presentation. Any file apart from /etc/network/interfaces is there ?  Looking foreword for help.

Comment: Simplest thing i suggest is , read `ifconfig` code and you will get some hint.

Comment: `cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethX---> X here 0 or 1 as per eth interface`.

Comment: `ifconfig` isn't looking to `/etc/network/interfaces` at all and actually most systems where it is being used even don't have such a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the manual man. just run command *man ifconfig* in your terminal and at bottom it says 
it comes from these three files:

```
FILES
       /proc/net/socket
       /proc/net/dev
       /proc/net/if_inet6
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score -1):

IN computer to look up hostnames and IP addresses go to  /etc/hosts file.
here **ifconfig** displays the status of the currently active interfaces you only view the information not access.